# Get the Product description from WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I built a custom payment gateway extension for woocommerce and I'm posting all the data (item name, cost, quantity etc) in JSON format back to the payment provider.

However, I can't seem to get the item description to go through.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have that in cart object items, when getting an instance of the WP_post object, this way:

```
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item){
    // Get an instance of Product WP_Post object
    $post_obj = get_post( $cart_item['product_id'] );

    // HERE the product description
    $product_desciption = $post_obj->post_content;

    // The product short description
    $product_short_desciption = $post_obj->post_excerpt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**WooCommerce: Adding the Product Short Description to Archive Pages or Show Products Short Description on Shop Page**

```
function vitahc_excerpt_in_product_archives() {
the_excerpt();
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','vitahc_excerpt_in_product_archives', 10);
```